# Operator LIKE with MySQL dialect with input Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with a query that should return all providers with name containing the user's input. As an sql dialect MySQL is used:

```
Query(value = "SELECT * FROM provider WHERE name LIKE ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Provider> findProviderByName(String name);
```

So the `?1` does not work as I get the empty List. This is my configuration:

```
spring.application.name=farming-project
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/farm
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Any help?

Comment: @BarryCarter If I write it like this `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM provider WHERE name LIKE provider.name", nativeQuery = true)` then it just returns everything from the table, no point in user's input

Comment: Just as a test, try RLIKE

Comment: @BarryCarter wow that actually worked out. How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246867/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-iva-only-java).